# Magento. Values from Advanced search to be displayed in footer as list

Tags: magento, footer, advanced-search

In Magento I have attribute - brand. It's multiselect and appears in Advanced search.  What  I need is this values from Advanced search to be displayed in footer as list, like: Brand 1,  Brand 2... I need not the result of a search (not the products), but the brands names, so that user could click on brand name, and it will take him to the page with all products that have this brand attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. Obviously it's not the right and best way, but for my needs it's fine. I installed Free extension "Browse by Brand" (in Magento-connect, there are several). This extension creates a list of your brands in left-sider. I copied the chunk of code that creates a list (links to brands) and pasted it into footer. It's not the greate solution because I need to create brand separately in extension and in attributes.  As I said it's not the best way to do it, but it still might be useful for some one.

Answer (score 0):

Hello below code you will get brand name only not product link may be help you

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'computer_manufacturers'); //here, "computer_manufacturers" is the attribute_code
$allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
foreach ($allOptions as $instance) {
echo $instance['label'];
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I need , but Thank You!:)